# displaying special characters in IE

Tags: html, unicode

I have a webpage that uses the special character `&#xFE3E` in the HTML. In Firefox 4.0B12 this looks like a double downward-pointing chevron (︾). In Internet Explorer 8.0.7600.16385, however, this it just looks like `&#xFE3E`.

What do I need to do to get this character to display in IE the way it does in FF?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: Besides the obvious ; hints: Have you specified UTF8 encoding? What happens if you set the encoding to UTF8 manually in IE 8? Does IE 8 still display &#xFE3E when using Lucida Sans Unicode font?

Comment: Note though that entities require a semicolon at the end as well. `&#xFE3E` alone won't display anything other than the text itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly specify a font that you know contains that character (eg in a `font-family` CSS rule), so that you're not relying on the font fallback functionality of the browser (which varies, but Firefox is typically better at it than IE).

U+FE3E is a character intended for use as a close bracket in vertical ideographic text (Chinese, Japanese etc). You shouldn't expect it to be available on a machine that doesn't have East Asian fonts installed, and using it to get a particular shape unrelated to parentheses is really a misuse. I would not use it on the web. There are a limited number of ‘symbol’ characters that generally render reliably across the main OS default installs and this isn't one of them.

Comment: What recent OS does not have any Asian font supprt? IIRC XP was the last to exclude the fonts by default.

Comment: This won't be used on the Internet. If my PC will display it, then all the PCs that need to view the page should be able to see it. Is there a downward pointing version of `»` that is in the group that reliably render?

Comment: It is very thinkable that IE8 is a very very strict font-family interpreter that will not think of "grabing the first font on the system that may supports the unicode entity".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to end the character reference with a semicolon, like `&#xFE3E;`.

Comment: Adding the semicolon makes it look like an empty box in IE and a box with the letters `FE3E` in FF.

Comment: Then you are using it correctly, since the browsers are trying to find a glyph for that character but can't. Either you need to choose a different font (look into typekit.org or Google Web Fonts even) or use an image/CSS sprites. For that matter, it works on my system; first try omitting any `font-family` rules.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the semi-colon after the HTML code: `&#xFE3E;`.

Comment: Adding the semicolon makes it look like an empty box in IE and a box with the letters `FE3E` in FF.

Comment: I was able to recreate the issue in IE, and adding the semicolon worked to resolve the issue. Are you sure you do not have some CSS styles hindering the display? An online example maybe?